# Не устанавливается puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Выдает такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установка через npm тоже выдает ошибки.

Comment: А вручную не пробовали на тот URL сходить, который в ошибке указан? Может там какая-то информация написана, почему там 403 выдаётся.

Comment: @CrazyElf, там просто текст с ошибкой:
Google-Edge-Cache: forbidden
Error: 7